# Structuring user-entered data - design/architecture

Tags: input

I am working on an outdoor site and letting users enter the types of things they saw when they are outdoors.  Obviously any item can be written in a large number of ways.

For example, the animal "coyote" can be written like this:

```
coyote,
wolf,
coyotes, 
wild coyotes,
cayotees
```

So if I let users enter data, how can I have the system understand that all the above examples are about something classified as a "coyote" ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to rely on [Google Sets](http://labs.google.com/sets?hl=en&q1=coyote&q2=&q3=&q4=&q5=&btn=Small+Set) for each new entry then create links with already existing matched entries in your system ?

You could even crowdsource the validity checking of the links by adding a "Report non related" function.

There are various (non offical) versions of [Google Set API](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22google+sets+api%22).

Comment: @Genadinik: Did this provide you with any help?

Comment: You know....not too much help :) Maybe mainly because I have not tried it. But also your answer is worded a little bit awkwardly and it is hard to understand how this should work.  How would google sets work with my MySQL data?  Do they co-exist?  Or I have to switch?

Comment: @Genadinik: You wouldn't have to switch. Both would co-exist. For each and every word in your system, you'd call the Google Set API, retrieve and store the results. You'd have to create some kind of weighted "link" between the "master" word and the Google sets proposals. Every good link should see its weight improved. Every bad link should be removed. Then, you'd regularly resubmit every "master" along with its direct related (provided the link > 0), the new results sent by Google Set should be more and more closely related. Of course, the system would have to be trained for a while.